# Pandas: selecting multiple columns programmatically

Tags: python, pandas

Right now, I select multiple rows where certain columns have a particular value this way:

```
df.loc[(df['col1'] == val1) & (df['col2'] == val2)]
```

Is there a way I can do this programmatically, I provide the column key/value as a dict? Something like this:

```
def get_df(cols)

   df.loc[ (df[k] == v) for k,v in cols.items() ]
```

But I'm not sure how to 'AND' the expressions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Series from the dictionary and make the comparison:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (100, 3)), columns = list("ABC"))
cols = {"A": 0, "B": 3, "C": 3}

df[(df == pd.Series(cols)).all(axis=1)]
Out: 
    A  B  C
94  0  3  3
```

Or, use [`np.logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) with [`reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df[k] == v) for k,v in cols.items()])]

    A  B  C
94  0  3  3
```